# Create Silverlight DatePicker control programmatically

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

I am trying to add a DatePicker control to my page programmatically, but intellisense is not picking  up the DatePicker type as I would expect.

MSDN shows this control as being part of System.Windows.Controls

I have referenced this assembly in my project, and in my usings statement, but still VS cannot recognise the DatePicker type.

I would expect this to work:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        public partial class MyClass : UserControl
        {
            ...


            public void MyMethod
            {
                DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

            }

            ...
        }
    }
```

> Compiler Error: The type or namespace
>   name 'DatePicker' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed and readded the reference to System.Windows.Controls and this worked. The references must have gotten screwed up along the way - not the first time this has happened, and I'm sure it won't be the last :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Datepicker is not included in the silverlight runtime, (I could be worng).

There is an [opensource project at codeplex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/.) that has a control that provides this functionallity.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. This is the control I am taking about, it can be seen on their wiki http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%201 derives from the System.Windows.Controls namespace as defined above.